# Can we increase the tag length limit?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

The 25 character limit on tag names has always been a problem for this site, due to our policy of tagging questions with the titles of the movies they're about as accurately as possible and the fact that those movies could often have rather long titles. This has lead to many compromises and workarounds and has largely been accepted as a natural fact, an unchangeable problem with the tagging system.

But before you call me out on exactly that and refer me to one of the many big disillusioning [main meta posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197889/162011) about this issue, see what actually *just happened* on [Meta Literature SE](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/761/50). It seems our paper-oriented colleagues were the final drop:

> This can be increased, but only up to a maximum of 35 characters...
>
> I increased the allowed length to 32...

So the tag length limit on Literature.SE just got **increased to 32 (out of possible 35)**, which marks a significant precedence for at least reducing a years-long problem. And in fact it already inspired similar per-site feature-requests using this precedent on [Science-Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11018/23386), [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/112299) and possibly others.

I'd thus hereby chime into this exciting new development and open this up for reconsideration here, too. So, **can we please increase the tag length limit on our site** (if not the whole network), preferably to the maximum of 35, or at least the 32 Literature got?

---

Apparently, [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12510/112299) also got a (trial) increase to the full 35 characters in the wake of this.

Comment: Definitely needed by M&TV.

Comment: Could not agree more with this request.

Comment: I am all for it.

Comment: We should or we must.

Comment: @AnkitSharma We must. It will solve the problem of using abbreviations and skipping articles while creating new tags. It'll also solve for similar long-titled movies.

Comment: I still personally think it's not long enough.  what if someone wants to ask a question about "Night of the Day of the Dawn of the Son of the Bride of the Return of the Revenge of the Terror of the Attack of the Evil, Mutant, Hellbound, Flesh-Eating Subhumanoid Zombified Living Dead, Part 2: In Shocking"?

Comment: @DForck42 How about [tag:NDDSBRRTAE-M-H-FE-S-Z-L-D-2-I-S]? It can fit 31. ;-) :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [has finally reached the whole network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/162011) and the new **maximum tag length is 35 characters**.

Comment: Is there any "tag renaming" planned by the mods like on S&F? https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11237/what-tags-should-we-rename-now-that-we-have-35-characters-in-tags Perhaps open a question where people can list the necessary improvements?

Comment: @BCdotWEB Well, we already renamed  a ton of tags as soon as the limit was increased anyway.

Comment: But of course, if you still see tags that would profit from a rename, feel free to bring them to notice.