# How to tag "National Lampoon's Christmas Vacation"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Despite the [length increase of tag names](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2822/can-we-increase-the-tag-length-limit) to 35 characters, there are still titles that exceed this limit. Case in point: ***National Lampoon's Christmas Vacation***. Strip the apostrophe and replace the spaces with dashes, and you end up with a 36 character tag.

In this case I've decided to remove the "s" as well, so now it's https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/national-lampoon-christmas-vacation .

Was this the best approach?

Comment: There already is an existing tag for this movie anyway, called [tag:christmas-vacation].

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Ah OK. So what best to do? Can `national-lampoon-christmas-vacation` be made a synonym of the existing tag?